# Роутинг SPA на Django+Vue.js

Tags: python-3.x, django, vue.js, url, vue-router

Есть приложение на `django`, фронтенд которого написан на `Vue.js`:

1. Подразумевается, что `django` участвует только в раздаче статики и выдаче `index.html`
2. Дальнейший роутинг управляется непосредственно на стороне фронтенда.
3. Параметр `mode` в роутере `Vue` установлен в `history`
4. `index.html` выдается по `/controlpanel/`
5. `Rest API` выдается по `/controlpanel/api/`

В связи с этим имеем код:

**views.py:**

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

def index(_):
    html = open(os.path.join(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0], "index.html")).read()
    return HttpResponse(html)

#заглушка
def api(_):
    return HttpResponse('api')
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from controlpanel.views import index, api

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', api),
    path('', index),
]
```

**/routers/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Hello from '@/components/Hello'
import NotFoundComponent from '@/components/NotFoundComponent'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: '/controlpanel',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Hello',
      component: Hello
    },
    { path: '*', component: NotFoundComponent }
  ]
})
```

В результате `django` выдает `index.html` по `/controlpanel/`, но если из браузера перейти в `/controlpanel/<any_url>/` то `django` выдает свою `404` страницу.

**Вопрос:** как сделать так, чтобы `vue.js` обрабатывал все `url` после `/controlpanel/` не прибегая к `mode: 'hash'`?

Comment: Все url попадают в vue.js по умолчанию. Что у вас не получается?

Comment: @RomanC Если вставить в адресную строку _/controlpanel/<any_url>/_ то any_url не дойдет до Vue Router, потому что django выдаст 404 ошибку.

Comment: Есть вариант дублировать урлы из vue в django, но как по мне, такой костыль вообще не вариант...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел следующее решение (если это можно назвать решением):

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from controlpanel.views import index, api

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', api),
    re_path('^.*$', index),
]
```

В документации написано, что `re_path` является алиасом для `url()`, который в свою очередь поддерживает такую конструкцию, как  `'^.*$'`, что позволяет отдать одно представление на все неизвестные урлы. Но так-как re_path это временное решение, и возможно, в будущем, оно будет удалено из новых версий django, вопрос все еще открытый. Если можно как нибудь реализовать это без использования re_path, это будет отличным решением.

**P.S.** `path('.*', index)` к сожалению, работать не хочет.